# Difference between Arraylist.forEach() and Arraylist.replaceAll()

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach, replaceall

I have a question about the difference between `Arraylist.forEach()` and `Arraylist.replaceAll()`. I know that `Arraylist.forEach()` is used to perform an action for each element in the list, but it seems that `Arraylist.replaceAll()` does the exact same thing. But for some reason, when you decide to do `a.forEach(e -> e.concat("test");` assuming a is an Arraylist of Strings, the Arraylist does not concatenate "test" to the end of each String in the Arraylist. However, if you do `a.replaceAll(e -> e.concat("test");`, the concatenation works. Why is this the case? An example of what I am talking about is in this image:

[image: this image].

The answer is B, but C seems to make the most sense to me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `concat` returns a new string, but `forEach` ignores the return value of the lambda expression. `replaceAll` does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat-java.lang.String-) returns a new string, but [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) ignores the return value of the lambda expression. (Its declared parameter is a `Consumer`, which has no return value.)

[`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) puts the return value from its function back into the list. That is what it is for.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that strings are immutable. You are not assigning the return value of `concat`to anything when you call `forEach()`, but `replaceAll()` does since it overwrites the current element each time.

Answer (score 0):

`.forEach()` takes each individual element of the list and then applies the function. Normally you would call a function of an object. In this case you throw the returned value away and does not change the object.

`.replaceAll()` takes each individual element of the list and applices a function. After that the returned value will be set on the specific place.

`.concat()` does not change the string reference due to the string immutability, but it will return the changed string in a new reference.

Answer (score 0):

The names explain exactly what the methods do.

forEach pass each element to the function, but it doesn't modify the array member as long as the object is of an immutable type. Consequently it expects no return value (void) of the function. The array always remain unchanged.  String type is immutable, so any change doesn't influence the object being held in the array.

replaceAll pass all array members to the function and checks the object return by that function, and of course store that object back to the array, meaning replace. Note that in this method the function must return an object. In case of String.concat the concatenated String is returned thus that concatenated String appears in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think it happens because

1. a.forEach iterates over each element in the arrayList, then Concat returns a new string. It does not change the original string in the arrayList.
2. a.Replaceall will replace the original string in the arrayList.